# Center overflown text container

Tags: html, css, layout, text, flexbox

[image]

As the picture shows, I need to get rid of the area roughly indicated with the red circle. The aim is to horizontally center the second radio button with its label like the one above and below. This extra undesired width comes about due to the text overflow and the word breaking to the next line when there is not enough width for it all to go on one line.

- Note that the aim is to center the radio button and label together i.e. the space between the radio button's right edge and the label's left edge should remain the same.
- Also, the second line should not center horizontally, but start from below the radio button as it is already.

Here's a barebone example of the issue:
http://codepen.io/KristjanLaane/pen/ryQZoM

### HTML

```
<body>
  <div>
    <input id="radio1" type="radio" name="choice">
    <label for="radio1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="radio2" type="radio" name="choice">
    <label for="radio2">Phasellus rutrum scelerisque. Aenean longwordhere tomakethepoint ultricies.</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="radio3" type="radio" name="choice">
    <label for="radio3">Cras auctor justo metus.</label>
  </div>
</body>
```

### CSS

```
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

label {
  background: yellow;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

Comment: via fixing width of your `div` maybe.

Comment: Not possible with CSS alone...that's not the way the line-box model works.

Comment: This might get you closer though - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/KWrGxm

Comment: @Paulie_D as far as i can see adding flex:0 0 auto to input makes the radio button center vertically, but the aim is to center both the radio button and its label horizontally. you probably know that already though :)

Comment: @Paulie_D a javascript solution then perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Break the lengthy word to cover the white space by using     `word-break: break-all;`

```
label {
    background: yellow;
    font-size: 25px;     
    word-break: break-all;
  }
```

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oZQaEJ)**

Comment: Actually thats what not OP wants.

Comment: yes, unfortunately breaking text by letter is not desired